# How to add automatically the imports in a Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, import

I generate (from a progam java) some Java classes but actually, I don't add the import in each class. I'd like to have a kind of parser that is able to see which import needs to be added in a class. Maybe, it's possible to reuse the fonctionnality of Eclipse because it's able to do that. However, I don't know where I can find that.

Do you have any idea?

Many thanks,

Bat

Comment: it's Java and not JAVA http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/why-do-so-many-people-write-java-instead-of-java

Comment: How can it possibly know which import you want? If I have an org.robertgrant.Random that I want to use, but just specify Random, should it pick that or java.util.Random? What about if in another class, where I want to use java.util.Random instead? How can it know which I want to use? It can't. That's why you have imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using only Full Qualified Names for classes when creating the code for the generated Java classes?

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do about name collisions?  You use a "Date" - is it java.util.Date or java.sql.Date?  You use a "XMLFoo", is it com.foomatics.XMLFoo or is it org.openfoo.XMLFoo?  It's better to add the imports as you add the code.

Maybe you can create a HashSet of all the imports you're going to need as you generate the code, and then add them in at the top when you're done?

Comment: I'm aware about this problem. I only ask if it's possible to reuse the code of eclipse to add automatically the imports?

Comment: @user376112 eclipse will pop up a dialog and prompt you to select an import from a list, if there are collisions. How will your code handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I see now... the problem is definitely on your generator. Work on that because even if you can extract the functionality from Eclipse, you won't get a 100% working solution every time. So my suggestion is just forget it and fix your generator.

<strike>As Paul said, you have to decide the imported class yourself. I usually type on Eclipse and at the end of the class I press Ctrl+Space to get some suggestions. So, for example I want to have `java.util.Date`, I will write `Date` and then Ctrl+Space and select `java.util.Date` and Eclipse will automatically import `java.util.Date` for me.</strike>

If the code is already there, I will do quick fix (F1 on Eclipse) and it will also suggest some fixes to the code I have (one of them is to import the suitable class).

Comment: My code is generated automatically  by a server, so I can't use eclipse.